# What to do with the response of Street View Image API?

Tags: image, google-maps, google-street-view

I just started using the Street View Image API, but when I call it, all it returns is just a huge unreadable string.

How am I supposed to turn that string into an actual image? Thanks.

Here's my AJAX request I made using jQyuery:

```
        $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        data: {
            size: "600x300",
            location: "46.414382,10.013988",
            heading: "151.78",
            pitch: "-0.76",
            key: key
        }
    });
```

Comment: show your code .. please

Comment: @scaisEdge I added it to the question, thanks.

Comment: With this what what's your goal  .. this code, if work, return the image .. and the log the result in console is not useful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by  @scaisEdge it returns an image, use the URL directly as `src` of an `<img>`:

```js
jQuery(
  function($) {
    $('#streetview')
      .attr('src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?' + $.param({
        size: "600x300",
        location: "46.414382,10.013988",
        heading: "151.78",
        pitch: "-0.76",
        //key:key
      })).show();
  }
);
```

```css
#streetview {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="streetview" />
```

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason it doesn't work if I perform an AJAX request and set the src of the image as the request's response.